# How to share an object between two controllers in angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

How to share an object between two controllers in angular JS?

These are my controllers:
//First ctrl

```
idxcontrollers.controller('myCtrl',function($scope,$location,$rootScope,productService) {
$scope.rowClick = function(item){
//i want to pass a item obj to rowCtrl
$location.path('/detail/'+item.id);
}
}
//Second Ctrl
idxcontrollers.controller('rowCtrl',function($scope,$location,$routeParams,productService) {
    //here i want to get item obj.
});
```

Here i do not want to pass a obj.value1 or obj.value2. first of all i want to pass a whole object then in second Ctrl i will spearate them based on their values.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919962/angular-share-data-between-controllers

Comment: use a service and inject it into your controllers